# Issue with different packageName used in debugger vs runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

If the flavor used specifies the applicationId as being com.example.boo and the manifest packageName is com.example.foo.
If i attempt to debug an activity and do an evaluate expression with `findViewById(R.id.sampleView)` it will return that resource was not found, because the R class belongs to com.example.foo, if i do it like `it.resources.getResourceName((it.contentView as ViewGroup).getChildAt(3).id)` it shows that the name is com.example.boo:id/sampleView 
I found in the official documentation a [subnote](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the_package_name) mentioning this behaviour.
But nothing telling me how to actually debug, because all expressions using resources will return false negatives/positives, since it cannot find the resources in question.
How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your app's build.gradle file in section `defaultConfig` make your applicationId not include parts which you are using as flavors. For Example: you appId 'com.example.foo' and then name your flavors 'flav1' and 'flav2'. In that case you will have appId the same as your packageName and there should not be such problems with R file.
Your application will consists of applicationId(com.example.foo)+flavorName(flav1) = com.example.foo.flav1

Comment: in the defaultConfig i have applicationId = com.example.boo same as the manifest,
the flavor overrides it as com.example.foo

Comment: How about not override applicationId but just add flavor as suffix to existed applicationId. In that case you wouldn't have your problem described in your post.

Comment: in my case i cannot do that, my application deserves different clients, so i cannot common applicationId parts